# Suppose $B$ is an invertible integer matrix and $\det B = \pm 1$. Why must $B^{-1}$ be an integer matrix by Cramers rule?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $B$ is an $n \times n$ invertible matrix with integer entries.

Suppose I know $\det B = \pm 1$.

How is it then "obvious" by use of Cramers rule that $B^{-1}$ also has integer entries ?

I know Cramers rule reads: $$Bx = b \Rightarrow x_{i} = \frac {\det B_i} {\det B} = \frac {\det B_i} {\pm 1}$$

I see that this give me information regarding $x$, but it should provide information regarding $B^{-1}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take the standard basis of $V_n$, $\{e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_n\}$.
$$B\text{ invertible} \implies Bx=b\text{ has unique solution for all }b\in V_n,\text{ namely }x=B^{-1}b$$
Columns of $B^{-1}$ are $B^{-1}e_1,\;B^{-1}e_2,\;\ldots,B^{-1}e_n$ where $B^{-1}e_k$ has components of the form $\frac{\det B_i}{\pm 1}$, which are clearly integer numbers, $i=1,2,\ldots,n$.

Answer (score 4):

By Cramer's rule, the inverse of the matrix can be formed from the transpose of the matrix of cofactors of the matrix, divided by the determinant. If all the elements of the matrix are integers, the cofactors are just sums and products of integers so they are integers, and the determinant is one or minus one, so the inverse must consist of integers.

Comment: Will you write a concise formula ? I might understand it better then, how you apple Cramers rule.

Comment: You can [find the formulas in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule).